# Render php array within an array in mustache

Tags: php, mustache, kohana-3.3, kostache

My array "$groupData" looks like this:

```
 array(3) (
    0 => array(3) (
        "id" => string(1) "2"
        "name" => string(20) "Super Administrators"
        "permissions" => array(3) (
            "system" => integer 1
            "superuser" => string(1) "1"
            "admin" => string(1) "1"
        )
    )
    1 => array(3) (
        "id" => string(1) "3"
        "name" => string(10) "Publishers"
        "permissions" => array(4) (
            "system.pub.add" => integer 1
            "system.pub.delete" => integer 1
            "system.pub.edit" => integer 1
            "system.pub.publish" => integer 1
        )
    )
    2 => array(3) (
        "id" => string(1) "4"
        "name" => string(7) "Authors"
        "permissions" => array(3) (
            "system.pub.add" => integer 1
            "system.pub.delete" => integer 1
            "system.pub.edit" => integer 1
        )
    )
)
```

I am having trouble rendering the `permissions` part of my code. I have tried using `{{#groupData}}{{#permissions}} {{.}} {{/permissions}}{{/groupData}}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `{{ . }}`... You're trying to render an associative array as a string, and that just doesn't work in PHP:

```
<?php
echo array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2); // no me gusta :)
```

Like most things Mustache, the answer here is to prepare your view. What exactly would you expect it to render that array as? JSON? If so, make it explicit:

```
<?php
foreach ($data['groupData'] as $key => $group) {
    $data['groupData'][$key]['permissionsJSON'] = json_encode($group['permissions']);
}

$tpl = "{{# groupData }}{{ permissionsJSON }}{{/ groupData }}";

$m = new Mustache_Engine;
echo $m->render($tpl, $data);
```

If you want it available as pairs of key/value, do that explicitly:

```
<?php
foreach ($data['groupData'] as $key => $group) {
    $permissions = array();
    foreach ($group['permissions'] as $key => $val) {
        $permissions[] = array('key' => $key, 'val' => $val);
    }
    $data['groupData'][$key]['permissions'] = $permissions;
}

$tpl = "{{# groupData }}{{# permissions }}{{ key }}: {{ val }}{{/ permissions }}{{/ groupData }}";

$m = new Mustache_Engine;
echo $m->render($tpl, $data);
```

Do you just want to iterate over a list of the keys?

```
<?php
foreach ($data['groupData'] as $key => $group) {
    $data['groupData'][$key]['permissions'] = array_keys($group['permissions']);
}

$tpl = "{{# groupData }}{{# permissions }}{{ . }}{{/ permissions }}{{/ groupData }}";

$m = new Mustache_Engine;
echo $m->render($tpl, $data);
```

Comment: Changed my code and used the key/value part. Works like a charm.